# SQL - Error: ORA-01722

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm having an issue with the following piece of code

[image]

I am getting an error message:

> ```
> SQL Error: ORA-01722: invalid number
> 01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
> *Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
> *Action:   Specify a valid number.
> ```

I am really new to SQL, could someone please help me figure out where I went wrong?

Thank-you

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Huh?  Just do:

```
insert into diner (col1, col2, . . .)  -- list the columns here
    values (4912, 0, 3, timestamp '2017-05-02 20:30:00', timestamp '2017-05-02 22:25:00');
```

Notes:

- List the columns being inserted.  This is probably the root cause of your problem.
- You don't have to convert a string to a date/time.  You can use `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP`.
- Subqueries are not necessary.